# Pi NoIR Camera is dead?

Tags: camera

I have been working with Raspberry Pi + PiNoir Camera for 5 months now. Everything was working fine till I tried to attach my pi-camera to my room's ceiling. To stick the camera to the ceiling I used a **tape** on the back side of camera's Flex Cable. Also I placed the camera on an **aluminium surface**. Now I get this error when I use my cam

```
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 
vc.ril.camera'(1:EN OMEM) mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not 
create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1) mmal: Failed to create camera 
component mmal: main: Failed to create camera component mmal: Camera is not detected
```

I read on [raspberryforum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=102292) that above error means that my camera is dead. If yes why did it happen? Can I do anything to rectify this error. What important cautions should we take while using camera?

Comment: http://www.phys.hawaii.edu/ams02/outreach/em_scotch.php

Comment: Also, aluminum is a conductor, so I wouldn't place any powered PCB on top of it.

Comment: so is the camera as whole gone bad ? or just the flex cable?

Comment: Pull it off the aluminum and see if it works again.